# When the browser is zoom out, my web page looks bad!. Why?

Tags: html, css

When I use zoom out in Internet Explorer, the page zooms out but not as uniform. It looks ugly. What is the reason for that? Help me plz

After Zoom out (look at the three boxes):

http://www.flickr.com/photos/41695354@N08/4233473080/

Comment: look that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403438/how-to-deal-with-zoom-in-responsive-layouts

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice article

[Page Zoom, Elastic Layouts & Em (Erratic Moustaches)](http://dialdfordesign.com/?p=185)

and read

[Why browser zoom shouldn’t kill flexible layouts](http://zomigi.com/blog/why-browser-zoom-shouldnt-kill-flexible-layouts/)

[Web Browser Zoom: Design consequences](http://www.tibobeijen.nl/blog/2009/03/07/web-browser-zoom-design-consequences/)

Answer (score 2):

There are two different zoom modes.

**Font zoom**, this resizes the font size and all elements that are coupled with it.

**Full page zoom**, resizes the whole page and all elements. Only supported in modern browsers.

In your case I believe it's the font zoom that affects all sizes given in `em`. That means some elements on your page get resized and others not.

The simplest way around it is to give all dimensions in `em` instead of `px`, `cm`, `pt`.