# How to deal with zoom in responsive layouts?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, zooming

How to deal with zoom in responsive layouts ?
All get messy when zooming this site : http://bostonglobe.com/
I loved the layout and responsive effects but sometimes my user will zoom content.
Thanks

Comment: Actually in my opinion, the site held together pretty well when zoomed, the divs stayed aligned, no div was over another div, no text came over the images etc. With zooming, you have to live with some degradation, specially if zoomed to much, since horizontal space becomes less each time you zoom in. Techniques to handle it are many, some of them is never to give size in pixels, and all lengths, widths and heights are given in percentage.

Answer (score 3):

Simply avoid fixed units and use percentage or em units for your elements.

Zoom is a useful feature browsers provide to users surfing your site, and it will mess up your text and layout to some extent anyway.

The best thing you can do is make sure your site is completely zoomable, not going against this feature.

Comment: I was looking for it too , help for answer but what is a zoomable site?

Comment: By "zoomable site" I mean a site which help the browser achieving the zoom effect, rather than going against it, so the site will adapt more nicely when the user will zoom it.